# Angular JS UT to verify whether a method on service is called or not

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a controller like below

```
(function () {
    var newPlaceController = function ($scope, PlacesService, $mdDialog) {

        $scope.newPlace = {
            "city": "",
            "country": ""
        };
        $scope.addCity = function () {
            $scope.places.push($scope.newPlace);
            PlacesService.addCity($scope.newPlace);
            $mdDialog.hide();
        };
        $scope.cancel = function(){
            $mdDialog.hide();
        };
    };

    angular.module("module.place")
        .controller('NewPlaceController', newPlaceController);

}());
```

Also I have a test file like below which tests whether the initialization value of newPlace is correct.The code is like below

```
describe("NewPlaceController", function () {

    var $scope, ctrl;

    beforeEach(module("module.place"));

    beforeEach(
        inject(function (_$controller_) {
            $scope = {};
            controller = _$controller_('NewPlaceController', {
                $scope: $scope
            });
        }));

    describe("Initialization", function () {
        it("asdasd", function () {
            expect($scope.newPlace).toEqual({
                city: ''
                , country: ''
            });
        })
    });

});
```

It's working fine. My doubt is how can I test the addCity and cancel functions in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this

```
it("Should call addCity", function () {
   var spy = spyOn(PlacesService, 'addCity');
   controller.addCity();
   expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
})

it("Should call mdDialog hide", function () {
   var spy = spyOn($mdDialog, 'hide');
   controller.cancel();
   expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Comment: what is this sinon ?  am getting error saying ReferenceError: sinon is not defined